# Ellipsis doesn't work

Tags: android

I have an edittext and I want to show 3 dots at the end when the text is longer than the edittext.

I found that there is a method setEllipsize so I've used that, but it is not working..
This is my code:

```
    edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    edt.setFocusable(false);
    edt.setCursorVisible(false);
    edt.setMaxLines(1);
    edt.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    edt.setSingleLine(true);
    edt.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
```

I've tried to add multiple parameters as you can see, but none of them are working.

Any more options I can try?

Comment: Try removing: edt.setMaxLines(1); AND/OR edt.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);

Comment: Not able to test right now but try: tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);

Answer (score 0):

//try setting the Ems

```
edt.setMaxEms(5);
```

or

```
android:maxEms="5"
```

**NOTE:** you can adjust the ems size as how many chars you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Or in XML file set these for the editText

```
android:inputType="text"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

SetEllipsize  will work in TextView Try that

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're using setEllipsize with InputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT

For some reason these 2 don't work together :(